# Working with Lists in Razor View - Incorrectly Looping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, html.hiddenfor

I have been struggling with getting a list returned in my Razor View page. I am passing data to my controller which connects to my service to retrieve the data for me. This works without issue.

However, when I pass it to my Razor View page, it has a problem with the objects. I ended up doing a foreach loop but there are certain object properties that should not be considered a list. When I try to use the "@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.State)" it no longer works and my result output is just a mess of loops on the page. This is the first time I have worked with lists on here and was hoping someone could suggest a way where I can do a foreach loop in some areas where I need it and then have a FirstOrDefault, or something to that effect for the properties that I do not want to iterate over as they are only indicators (e.g. isEmail = 1, for example).

[ Controller ]

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult GetFilters(MembershipVM model)
{                         
    var results = _service.GetFilters(model).ToArray().ToList();
    model.EmailCount = results.Count();

    if (model.EmailCount == 0)
    {
        TempData["ReturnType"] = "Failure";
        TempData["ReturnMessage"] = "No Members were found using the search criteria entered.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("SendEmail", results); // passes list to Razor View
    }
}
```

[ View ]

```
@using Otan.Models.Members
@using Otan.Web.Helpers
@model List<MembershipVM>

....
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="bold panel-title">Filters Selected</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            @if (Model.Zip.ToString() != 0)  @* I get an error here and with every other object in the model *@
            {
                @:<li>By proximity to ZIP Code: within <b>@Model.Distance</b> miles of Zip Code <b>@Model.Zip</b></li>
            }
....
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.State)  @* this does not work either unless I include a foreach loop *@
....
```

TIA

-- Daisy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code you can use `Html.HiddenFor` without including it in a for-each loop

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> Model.FirstOrDefault().State)
```

as for the `if statement` you can use it the same way like this

```
@if(Model.FirstOrDefault().Zip != 0)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: I agree with you @FluffyKitten but the problem in the question was for only one specific line of code that didn't work.

Comment: It might only be a single line, but that doesn't mean you can't explain your code. Please edit the question to explain what it does and how it fixes the problem in the question.